# strings.Split never returns nil or zero length slice?

Tags: go, split

Here is a piece of my code in Go

```
ips := strings.Split(IP, ",")
if len(ips) < 1 {
    return fmt.Errorf("'%v' ip is wrong", ips)
}
```

I tested this and it seems that `ips` variable can never be nil. For example, an empty string produces a slice of empty string (length 1).

Do you think I can remove the `if` block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right: `strings.Spit()` will never return a nil value. The result will be of type `[]string` with at least one element containing the given string.

Whether you can remove the if block depends: Does your code have a problem if `len(ips) < 2`? If it does not you can safely remove the if block.

If however e.g. you are only interested in `ips[1]` then you definitely need to check first.

Comment: I should complete my question "nil or zero length slice" If I run `strings.Split("", ",")` the length is 1 https://play.golang.org/p/Kaddfg9CiF

Comment: Output slice always has at least one element. It makes sense, even when you try to split empty string, function will return slice with one element - empty string.